# "O.R. they?" from Rushmore movie

Tags: cinema

what's the point of this joke:

**max:** I like your nurse's uniform, guy.

**dr.:** These are O.R. scrubs.

**max:** "O.R." they?

from rushmore movie:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMd2gB9L8So

trying translate this to russian but i'm stuck

Comment: It's sort of a pun. You'd expect someone to say "Are they?", but instead he's using the acronym.

Comment: jokes tend not to translate to Russian very well

Comment: It doesn't even translate into British English very well! I had no idea what "O.R." means (before I read @nj3ma's answer).

Comment: In the context of the movie, the pun isn't supposed to be very funny. The character is being obnoxious and rude (though that part is funny).

Comment: Yeah, there is no point, really, other than to have the guy act like a jerk.  (The final line is "Oh, are they?")

Answer (score 3):

The O.R is the operating room here. The joke is a pun on the O.R. O.R sounds like "oh, are".